# algebraic structure of Integral Steenrod squares

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, steenrod-algebra

It is well known that the classical Steenrod squares $Sq^a$ satisfy the Adem relations
$$Sq^aSq^b= \sum_c \binom{b-c-1}{a-2c}Sq^{a+b-c}Sq^c\;.$$
In the case where $a$ is odd, one can define an integral refinement
$$Sq_{\mathbb{Z}}^a=\beta(Sq^{a-1})\rho_2$$
where $\beta$ is the Bockstein corresponding to the sequence
$$\mathbb{Z} \overset{\times 2}{\to} \mathbb{Z} \overset{\rho_2}{\to} \mathbb{Z}/2.$$
This does indeed refine the usual Steenrod squares since $\rho_2\beta=\tilde{\beta}$ where $\tilde{\beta}$ is the Bockstein corresponding to 
$$\mathbb{Z}/2\overset{\times 2}{\to}\mathbb{Z}/4\to \mathbb{Z}/2$$
and $\tilde{\beta}(Sq^{a-1})=Sq^a$ for odd $a$. In the case where $a$ is even, it is easy to show using the Bockstein sequence that $Sq^a$ has no integral refinement.

**Question**: Do the integral refinements satisfy the Adem relations. That is, do we have
$$Sq_{\mathbb{Z}}^aSq_{\mathbb{Z}}^b= \sum_{c\ \mathrm{odd}} \binom{b-c-1}{a-2c}Sq_{\mathbb{Z}}^{a+b-c}Sq_{\mathbb{Z}}^c\;?$$
The statement at least seems plausible to me since for odd $a$ and $b$, the binomial coefficient
$$\binom{b-c-1}{a-2c}=0\ mod\ 2$$ 
for even values of $c$. Hence reducing mod 2 would recover the classical Adem relation.

Comment: Perhaps you have tried this already, but writing $Sq^a_\mathbb{Z} Sq^b_\mathbb{Z} = \beta Sq^{a-1}\rho_2 \beta Sq^{b-1} \rho_2 = \beta Sq^{a-1} Sq^b \rho_2$ and then trying to use the Adem relation for $Sq^{a-1} Sq^b$ might get you somewhere.

Comment: @MarkGrant Yep, that was my first thought. I think it will work, but there are some subtleties when working with the integral Bockstien $\beta$. For example, the Leibniz rule doesn't make sense a-priori. I'll probably just need to sit down and work it out.

Comment: I'm not sure you need the Leibniz rule, since these are compositions rather than products. I started writing an answer but got confused by mod 2 binomial coefficients. My feeling is that you will get some expression like you stated, but the coefficients will all be either $0$ or $1$.

Comment: @MarkGrant Ah yes of course. I'm not sure why I was thinking I would need Liebniz. It will be the formula will be the same but the coefficients will be $0$ when the binomial coefficient is even and 1 when its odd. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkGrant Unless I am mistaken, Bockstein always takes values in 2-torsion classes. So it does not really matter if you write full binomial coefficients or reduce mod 2, does it?

Comment: @SebastianGoette Thats right. The Bockstien is a homomorphism with domain a $\mathbb{Z}/2$ vector space so it takes values in 2-torsion.

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~reg/diffops.ps ? There Wood discusses some sort of algebraic integral lift of Steenrod operations,   I don't know if they correspond to cohomology operations over integers, though.

Comment: As an addendum to @user43326 suggestion, I suggest you look at Wood's `Problems in Steerod algebra' which I think you may find in his homepage as well. As suggested above, a kind of integral squaring operator already exists, and so there maybe something on their algebraic structure somewhere in the literature.

Comment: @user51223 I looked at that paper briefly, but it wasn't immediately clear to me how these operations corresponded to the ones introduced by Atiya and Hirzebruch which appear as differentials in the AHSS (these are exactly the ones I mentioned above). Still, I am sure a closer look at the paper would be worthwhile. Thanks.